Error: "Content type is not Multipart/Form-data" for large PDF/JPG uploads
I'm encountering an issue when trying to upload files larger than 10MB. when I attempt to upload a PDF or JPG file that exceeds this size, I receive the following error message:
Error: Content type is not Multipart/Form-data
However, smaller files (under 10MB) upload without any issues.
Here’s the code I’m using to handle the file upload:
r.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w, r.Body, 32<<20+1024)//reader, err := r.ParseMultipartForm(maxFileSize)
reader, err := r.MultipartReader()
if err != nil {
   fmt.Println("server.go:FileUpload:Error during MultipartReader:", err)
   err = fmt.Errorf(err.Error())
   return nil, err
}

fmt.Println("server.go:FileUpload:NO Error during MultipartReader:") 

What could be causing this problem, and how can I resolve it?

MultipartReader will return that error (ErrNotMultipart) when the request has no Content-Type header, or that header is empty.
This can be determined by inspecting the source for the MultipartReader method.
i.e. the cause of your problem seems to lie with the client making the request and failing to provide this header correctly for larger files.

Thank you for your response!.  After reviewing the headers for both small and large file uploads, i have confirmed that the Content-Type header is present and correctly set to multipart/form-data in both cases, so the issue doesn’t seem to be due to a missing or incorrect Content-Type in the request.
Here’s a comparison of the headers for small and large file uploads:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q9GFst6VY_ZejSHQjbZhIPa2t5oUX2aa/view?usp=drive_link
I'm still facing the issue, and any assistance would be great!

I don't have access to whatever you have shared in your google drive; if you have additional relevant information I suggest you add it to your question.  Until then, if the behaviour and your code really is as you have described, the only possible explanation appears to be a missing or malformed Content-Type header at the point at which MultipartReader is called, since these are the only two conditions under which the error you are seeing is returned.  Could the request headers be mutated by any middleware before reaching this handler, perhaps?

Here’s the updated link for more details; it is now accessible:
[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PIFDknQPpW8wnCYQ0U2jd9YGy75sP4cu/view?usp=sharing]

The presence of response headers as well as request headers suggests you collected this in the client.  The Content-Type header must have been removed or mutated by the time it reaches the server code you have posted, which - at the risk of becoming boring - is the only explanation for the error you are seeing.  You could confirm by inspecting the headers at that point.  The most likely explanation remains some middleware or other processing mutating the headers before the request reaches the code posted.  Could some proxy be interfering with larger uploads?

1.Set a Request Size Limit in http.MaxBytesReader
2.Check Content-Type and Log Details for Troubleshooting
3.Ensure the Route Can Handle Large Files
